# Red LED after `sudo halt`, may I unplug?

Tags: raspbian, power-supply, led

I flashed Raspbian and I use my Pi headless, connecting via SSH.
To power it off I do `sudo halt`, which disconnects me from the SSH. After a few green led blips I have steady red led on. Does it mean the Pi is still on and I cannot unplug the power?

I am asking this because I have seen a lot of SD card corruption in 2 days, so I was wondering if I have switched off improperly after the `sudo halt` while the red led was still on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may. Oh, have you considered `sudo shutdown`?

`shutdown` makes sure to run any shutdown tasks, clean up a bit, then power off gracefully (red LED will still be on on the pi, green LED will blink a few times to indicate shutdown is done. Unplug after that).

`halt` just kills the system.

<sub>Update: Turns out they're technically the same.</sub>

Comment: `halt` only kills the system immediately if you use `-f`, otherwise it and shutdown are much the same thing.  In fact they are exactly the same thing; have a quick look at `stat $(which halt)` and `stat $(which shutdown)`.  They just tell init to stop the system.  `halt -p` and `shutdown now` are identical, as are `halt` and `shutdown -H now`.  "Power off" is mostly meaningless on the pi because it cannot be powered off anyway -- I think the only difference is it turns off the HDMI & eth/usb bus.   The reason there are the two commands is purely historical.

Comment: I.e., Using `halt` is fine, particularly if you are going to unplug it.

Comment: @goldilocks Noted.

Comment: One day I will have to get the source and see what it actually does.

Comment: I was expecting the green light to go off but at least on my Pi 3, it stays on indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

If only the red LED is on, everything is good. It says, that your Raspberry PI is connected to a stable power supply. The green LED blinks a few times, when the shutdown process has finished, then it is safe to unplug the power supply. But depending on your raspbian version, it is better if you use the `shutdown` command.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically `shutdown` will "Halt, power-off or reboot the machine"
There was historically some difference.
The `man` for halt, poweroff, reboot states "These are legacy commands available for compatibility only"

AFAIK all should safely shutdown. 
In practice on Raspbian there still seems to be some differences.
`poweroff` should power the machine off, but the Pi has no power control.
`shutdown` (without any time parameter) has a delay before it actually shuts down.
`halt` should shut down immediately, but sometimes I find it closes network connections but does not shutdown.

In practice I use `poweroff` which results in the green LED flashing 10 times then shutting down.
Powering off after the flashing stops sems to be safe.

Comment: `shutdown` without a time or `now` will throw up the usage message - unless `systemd` on the (latest at time of writing) changes this. Traditionally `shutdown now` without any other options takes a running multi-user system (runlevels 2-5) down to single-user mode so the super-user can make changes (with a time delay the system should block `login`s from non-`root` users after the five-minute left deadline has expired). The `-h` option extends this to "halt" the system, and on non-RPis `-P` will switch power off.  I do recall that this has changed and one of these may now alias the other...

Answer (score 0):

Wait for system shutdown, it usually takes some time - about a minute or so. The red led is a power indicator