# Turning RPi off safely and elegantly

Tags: raspbian, power, shutdown

Raspberry Pi 1 Model A running Raspbian Stretch Lite here. What's the preferred method for elegantly shutting down the pi (so that all services shut down correctly & safely, etc.)?

Looks like I have several options:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo shutdown -P now
sudo poweroff
sudo halt -p
sudo init 0
```

**Or** I could just unplug the power and *let it crash* (I don't like this method).

Ideally my teardown procedure would be something like:

1. When I'm ready to shut it down, SSH into the RPi
2. Issue some command (see above -- any ideas?) to shut it down
3. Wait for all the onboard lights to turn off
4. Unplug the power (Micro USB) safely

Just wondering if there is a preferred/best practices way to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something worth noting from the manual page for `halt`, `poweroff` and `reboot` is:

> These are legacy commands available for compatibility only.

At the bottom is a "see also" for `systemctl`, and `man systemctl` has further details regarding the difference between the three things (in context, `systemctl halt`, `systemctl reboot`, etc).  As Milliways points out in a comment below, the three legacy commands are actually symbolic links to `systemctl`.<sup>1</sup>

My own preference is `halt` since it's the shortest to type; on machines that can be powered off I use `halt -p`.  However, this does not apply to the pi.

> `init 0`

This is an anachronism that, again, will work for backward compatibility.  However, if you are new to linux you should avoid it since [the init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), `systemd`, does not use SysV runlevels (so don't bother thinking in those terms).

> I could just unplug the power and let it crash

Please see "[Is it okay to just pull the plug?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50345/5538)".

---

<sup>1. They are still treated differently because the executable can check what name it was invoked with.</sup>

Comment: The `man` page does state that, and ALL are symlinks to `/bin/systemctl` (as are many other commands) **BUT** (at least on the Pi) they are **NOT** identical. I use `poweroff` because it provides a visual indication when shutdown is complete - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42188/8697

Comment: @Milliways If you mean the ACT 2 Hz blink followed by one long blink, I get identical behaviour for `shutdown now`, `poweroff`, and `halt`.

Comment: `poweroff` gives 10 binks at 1 second intervals. (At least it did on Jessie; I rarely power my Pi off and haven't checked recently.) I normally use `heartbeat` so the difference is obvious.